# how to use webclient post and redirect to destination

Tags: c#, post, header

I would like to post some INFO and HEADER to destinationA, if it is verified, it will redirect to destinationA and ask user login. The code below successful to pass INFO and HEADER to opponent, but throw exception error during  `byte[] result = client.UploadValues(Url, "POST", values);` , 408 request time out. 
and how do i redirect user to the destinationA if this problem is solve? Please help me.. i have no idea how to work this out after i try to google for few days...MANY THANKS in advance..

```
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
             values.Add(PDATA, "");

             string Url = "http://kh-api.mysabay.test/service/purchase/";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                client.Headers.Add("Authentication", "4");
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                byte[] result = client.UploadValues(Url, "POST", values);
                string ResultAuthTicket = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                return ResultAuthTicket;
            }
```

Comment: Seems like the server receiving the request is the problem. I would start there.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to set `Content-Type`. If it's not set, it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: To redirect, you could return a `301` with the `Location` header set.